# В чём отличие бага от исключения?

Tags: python, исключения, терминология

Подскажите, чем баг отличается от исключения в языке программирования Python?

Comment: Простыми словами, баг - это ошибка в коде, которая не обязательно приводит к *необрабатываемому* исключению, но вызывает глюки. А исключение - это не обязательно результат бага, если оно штатно обрабатывается и не приводит к падению программы или глюкам)

Comment: Если кратко - *баг* это когда программа работает не так, как надо, а *исключение* - специальный объект, который можно вызывать самому или вызывается сам при ошибке в программе.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Баг - необработанная ошибка в поведении программы, из за которой ты получаешь непредвиденное поведение или исключение. **Например:** Калькулятор на `5+5` отвечает `55`, так как ты забываешь преобразовать строку к цифре. В данном случае представлено неожиданное поведение (ведь исключение не вызывается)

Исключение - внутренняя ошибка которая вызывается специально, и которую можно и **нужно** перехватить. **Например:** Пользователь ввёл имя файла для чтения, но сам файл отсутствует. Метод для чтения файла вызывает исключение `FileNotFoundException`, но ты перехватываешь данное исключение и отправляешь сообщение пользователю, что введённый файл не существует.

Необработанное исключение - баг. **Например:** в калькулятор пользователь вводит `5/0`, и операция деления вызывает исключение `ZeroDivisionError`. Если ты его не обработаешь, то твоя программа просто крашнется. В данном контексте пофиксить баг - обработать это исключение - добавить метод для отлова данного исключения с помощью [`try` и `except`](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html) что бы вывести пользователю сообщение об ошибки.